# WooCommerce Undefined Property stdClass::$url

Tags: woocommerce

When i am installing woocommerce and logged out from my site then on home page woocommerce causes this problem.My wp-config.php is turned true , that is why its showing this error. but i need to know what is happening

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$url in /home/......./wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-page-functions.php on line 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 123 of that file is within the following piece of code:

```
function wc_nav_menu_items( $items ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $customer_logout = get_option( 'woocommerce_logout_endpoint', 'customer-logout' );

        if ( ! empty( $customer_logout ) ) {
            foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
                $path = parse_url( $item->url, PHP_URL_PATH );
                $query = parse_url( $item->url, PHP_URL_QUERY );
                if ( strstr( $path, $customer_logout ) || strstr( $query, $customer_logout ) ) {
                    unset( $items[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wc_nav_menu_items', 10 );
```

Notice on the last line there is a filter hook for `wp_nav_menu_objects`. So this function is used to filter the nav menu, and specifically looks like it is there solely so that WooCommerce can hide a logout menu object when the user is not logged in.

Now to the reason why the error is being thrown. I believe it stems back to the wordpress hook `wp_nav_menu_objects`. When looking at the function again it looks like the argument getting filtered named `$items` is expected to be a keyed array of stdClass instances, however on line 123 PHP is discovering that the `url` property is not available. This leads me to believe that another filter that occurs before this one is incorrectly modifying the `$items` array so that this filter can not correctly read the property.

Looking further in the file **wc-page-functions.php** on line 185 there is another hook for this filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wc_nav_menu_item_classes', 2 );
```

However checking `wc_nav_menu_item_classes` reveals that it does not do anything special either. So here are my suggestions based on what has been presented:

- Make sure that WordPress is up to date, the version of WooCommerce you are running maybe incompatible.
- If you have code that filters `wp_nav_menu_objects`, make sure that you have not introduced a bug that changes the `$items` array to no longer contain instances of stdClass.
- Try disabling/enabling 3rd party plugins that are not WooCommerce, you may find that one of these if out of date or just bugged.

Best of luck!

Koda